# MySQL ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'watched'?

Tags: mysql

I have this table definition:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE watched;
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(6) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| stream  | int(3) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| month   | date   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| watched | int(6) | NO   | UNI | 1       |                |
+---------+--------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And this is data inside:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM watched;
+----+--------+------------+---------+
| id | stream | month      | watched |
+----+--------+------------+---------+
|  1 |     11 | 2017-10-01 |       2 |
|  2 |     11 | 2017-10-01 |       1 |
+----+--------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When i run this query:

```
INSERT INTO watched (stream, month) VALUES (11, DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-01")) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE watched=watched+1;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'watched'
```

id is set to PRIMARY and AUTO_INCREMENT and watched is set as UNIQUE so that i can increase or decrease watched value with in sql statement watched=watched+1

But i don't know how to set up UNIQUE watched field to increase or decrease value by one...

EDIT:

This is table structure:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE watched;
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table   | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| watched | CREATE TABLE `watched` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stream` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `month` date NOT NULL,
  `watched` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `watched` (`watched`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: It sounds like `watched.watched` should simply not have a `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE  watched;`

Comment: I updated question with your query so you can take a look where i made mistake...thanks

Comment: Can you describe what your goal was with a `UNIQUE` constraint? It may be possible to achieve by other means, but to use `watched` as in counter value it can't be unique. Use `ALTER TABLE watched DROP INDEX watched` to remove the constraint.

Comment: My goal is to if watched have value 2 to increase if exists in table to 3 and so on...so i will try to rename watched.watched to watched.watch maybe is problem with same name as table name have unique name and mysql is confused what to do and throws error?

Comment: You don't need to rename the column. But it does not appear to be necessary to have the `UNIQUE` index on that column, and that is hindering your counter functionality. Your implementation of the counter with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is correct. What value should be `UNIQUE` is the `stream` a unique number, or the combination of `stream,month`? It seems that one the combination of _those_ columns should be unique, not their `watched` counter.

Comment: Yes you are right i removed UNIQUE frrom warched and add it to stream because if duplicate stream found update counter+1 and if not insert it..in above example you see that i have duplicate entries for stream and month...i will post solution now..thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

I just need to remove UNIQUE from watched.watched as per Michael suggestion using:

```
ALTER TABLE watched DROP INDEX watched
```

And create UNIQUE for stream as if is found increase counter+1 if not insert new record:

```
ALTER TABLE watched ADD UNIQUE (stream);
```

Now the error is gone and counter is increment+1 and all is working fine...God bless MySQL :)